# Angular 2 - inherit providers from base class

Tags: angular

I have the following BaseComponent.

```
@Component({
    providers: [PresetService, CollectionService, RecordService]
})
export class BaseComponent{
    constructor(private collectionService:CollectionService, private recordService:RecordService, private presetService:PresetService){
    }
}
```

Now all of the children should inherit the providers and it's instances:

I have the following BaseComponent.

```
@Component({ 
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}
```

That doesn't seem to be possible, as I need to call super from the child. So I would need to pass to provider instances from child to base. Is it possible that the parent can provide the instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f5c8e09

> Decorators:
>
> 1) list the decorators of the class and its parents in the
>   ancestor first order
>
> 2) only use the last decorator of each kind (e.g.
>   @Component / ...)
>
> Constructor parameters: If a class inherits from a parent class and
>   does not declare a constructor, it inherits the parent class
>   constructor, and with it the parameter metadata of that parent class.
>
> Lifecycle hooks: Follow the normal class inheritance model, i.e.
>   lifecycle hooks of parent classes will be called even if the method is
>   not overwritten in the child class.

As workaround you could use

```
const baseComponentProviders = [PresetService, CollectionService, RecordService];

@Component({
    providers: baseComponentProviders
})
class BaseComponent {

}
```

```
@Component({ 
    providers: baseComponentProviders
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}
```